# Hibernate 5.3, persist java.time.* truncating to microsecond

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-time

I've created a Spring Boot 2.x application using Spring JPA and Hibernate 5.3. I'm working with MySql 5.7. As DateTime columns in My DB have a 6 leght precision, I want to truncate the date to microseconds in my application before the value is stored in the DB.

In fact, if I don't do this, when I've a date like `2020-01-31T22:59:59.999999999Z`, in MySql is persisted as `2020-01-31T23:00:00.000000Z` and of course I don't want this!

I work with java.time.Instant in my application. I'm looking for a neat way to accomplish this for the entire application.
I'm conflicted if to use a custom Hibernate type or something else. I'd like some hint to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

### truncatedTo()

It’s easy enough when you know: use the `truncatedTo` method of the datetime class that you are using (perhaps `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime`). For example:

```
    Instant pointInTime = Instant.parse("2020-01-31T22:59:59.999999999Z");
    System.out.println("Original instant:          " + pointInTime);
    Instant truncated = pointInTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MICROS);
    System.out.println("Truncated to microseconds: " + truncated);
```

Output is:

> ```
> Original instant:          2020-01-31T22:59:59.999999999Z
> Truncated to microseconds: 2020-01-31T22:59:59.999999Z
> ```

It doesn’t work automatically across your application, though.

Link: [Documentation of `Instant.truncatedTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit))

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do know how to truncate Date in Java. The point is how to do that automatically before Hibernate persists the record in the DB.